# UDP Python: How to make the server broadcast messages the clients send in the UDP Chatroom

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, udp

I'm making a small chatroom application in Python using UDP sockets. I've set it up to where the user would choose their username and then send messages to the server. The server would then broadcast the message to every client connected. I managed to get the server working and the client is able to send messages to the server. The problem is the server isn't broadcasting the messages to the other clients connected.

Here is the server code:

```
    from socket import *
    import socket
    port = 1234
    localhost='127.0.0.1'
    #Create a socket



try :
    s = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1) 
    print ('Socket created')
except socket.error:
    print ('Error creating socket.')
    sys.exit()
#Bind the socket to port and localhost.
try:
    s.bind((localhost, port))
except socket.error:
    print ('Error while binding.')
    sys.exit()
print ('Bind complete.')    

while 1:
    # receive data from client (data, addr)
    d = s.recvfrom(2048)
    data = d[0]
    addr = d[1]

    if not data: 
        break
    print('Client connected at ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

    print('Message[' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]) + '] - ' +                     
    data.strip().decode("utf-8"))
    s.close()
```

Client Code:

```
from socket import *
import socket
import sys
port=1234
localhost='127.0.0.1'


try:
    s = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error:
    print ('Error creating socket.')
    sys.exit()
print ("Connected to chat")
Username= input('Please choose a username: ')
while(1) :
msg = input ('Enter message to send : ')

try :
    #Set the whole string
    s.sendto('{}: {}'.format(Username,msg).encode('utf-8'), (localhost,port)) 
    # receive data from server (data, addr)
    data = s.recvfrom(2048)
    reply = data[0]
    addr = data[1]

    print ( + reply.decode())

except socket.error:
    print ('Error sending message ' )
    sys.exit()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about what `socket.SO_BROADCAST` does. It doesn't cause all received messages to be broadcasted to all clients. It is used to let the network stack on the machine know that a socket can be used to send broadcast packets (by this I mean a packet with a destination address that is a deemed to be a "broadcast address" - this includes the network and broadcast addresses for a subnet, such as `192.168.0.0` or `192.168.0.255` for the subnet `192.168.0.0/24`).

To make your chat app work as you intend, you need to keep a log of all conncected clients and then whenever you receive a message you then can re-send it to all clients using `s.sendto()`.

Answer (score 1):

Hey mate you really should be using asyncio for this: 
(49mins) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzfHjytDceU

But what you need to do is create an object of users and then send them the data

Additionally you don't appear to be doing any sanitisation of the data: length and content should be limited. Basically:

```
from html import escape
clients = {}

...

msg = escape(msg_received[:2048])
for c in clients:
    c.send(msg)
```